# Extract ID on basis of TABLE priority

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE T( ID  VARCHAR2(100), DUEDAY VARCHAR(400))
CREATE TABLE T1( ID  VARCHAR2(100), DUEDAY VARCHAR(400))

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('500001', '13')
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('500002', '13')
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('500003', '13')
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('500001', '14')
SELECT T.* , 'T TABLE' FROM T

UNION ALL

SELECT T1.*, 'T1 TABLE' FROM T1
```

As you can see, data is present in table T1 for id 500001. If dueday is 14 then it should not extract on 13 even if it is present in table T.

[image]

expected output:
500002  500003

Comment: Not clear. Is this `select id from a where day = 13 and not exists (select 1 from b where id = a.id and day = a.day + 1)` what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I also don't understand your question. It's not clear what these two tables have to do with each other. If the day you run the query is relevant, then `SYSDATE` has to come into play somewhere.

Comment: So basically i have to pick the data on priority if B table has id 123 wirh date 14 then id shluld not extract on 13 when i execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1
                WHERE T1.DUEDAY = 13
UNION ALL
SELECT T.* FROM T 
               LEFT JOIN T1 ON t1.ID = t.ID
               WHERE T.DUEDAY = 13 AND T1.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Its not working for 14.

We need to extract the data on priority of table t1.
CASE 1
 If data is present in t1 = 14 and t= 13 then it should not extract on 13 then it come on 14.
CASE 2
if data is present on t1 = 13 and t= 13 then it should select on 13

Do let me know if you need more explanation on same

Comment: Updated the query, Please try this one.

Comment: Select * from (select * from t union select * from t1) abc
Where dueday = '13'
And not exists (select 1 from (select * from t union select * from t1) abcd where abc.id = abcd.id and to_number(abcd.dueday) > to_number(abc.dueday));

Comment: thanks Worked for me and this is the another way to do the same.